# Error trying to import Nuget PackageProvider

Tags: powershell, nuget

I have a computer behind a proxy and trying to get the Nuget package provider installed. I ran Install-PackageProvider -Name Nuget on a different PC on a different network and copied Nuget folder to $env:ProgramFiles\PackageManagement\ProviderAssemblies.

If I run Get-PackageProvider -ListAvailable it shows Nuget available.

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-PackageProvider -ListAvailable

Name                     Version          DynamicOptions
----                     -------          --------------
msi                      3.0.0.0          AdditionalArguments
msu                      3.0.0.0
nuget                    2.8.5.204
PowerShellGet            1.0.0.1          PackageManagementProvider,    Type, S...
Programs                 3.0.0.0          IncludeWindowsInstaller, IncludeSy...
```

However when I try to run Import-PackageProvider -Name Nuget I get the following error:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Import-PackageProvider -Name Nuget
Import-PackageProvider : No match was found for the specified search criteria and provider name 'Nuget'. Try 'Get-PackageProvider -ListAvailable' to see if the provider exists on the system.At line:1 char:1
+ Import-PackageProvider -Name Nuget
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo : InvalidData: (Nuget:String) [Import-PackageProvider], Exception 
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoMatchFoundForCriteria,Microsoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement.Cmdlets.ImportPackageProvider
```

Any suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: I tried importing using the full path and no errors were returned, however Nuget is still not listed when I run Get-PackageProvider.

Comment: Were you able to fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to work around the proxy by using the following:

```
$wc = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$wc.Proxy.Credentials = [System.Net.CredentialCache]::DefaultNetworkCredentials
$wc.Proxy.Address = "http://proxyurl"
```

Once I did this I was able to use Install-PackageProvider Nuget to install the proivder.

Comment: You should specify in your answer exactly what did you do once you executed the above script lines. It doesn't explain that.